# Good analogies between types in programming and structures, spaces and fields in mathematics?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, soft-question, computer-science

I am a programmer, and so my knowledge of math is limited to bare-bones calculus, linear algebra etc. Basically I know how to do the basic stuff, but never learned how to look at it in a more abstract sense.

I am trying to see if I can leverage my understanding of concepts within programming to get a better intuition about concepts in mathematics. I am well aware that there is no 1-to-1 mapping. So I am not looking for precise analogies but very rough analogies to help me build some intuition and make my journey into math-world a bit easier.

In programming , we operate with hierarchies of types, some which are abstract and others which are concrete. Concrete types can be instantiated to create objects. We can do thing with objects based on the type they belong to. So if I have an abstract type A, which concrete subtypes B and C, then instances of B and C will have some shared abilities because they share an abstract type A.

I am trying to map this thinking into my math reading. In programming , there is often a base type for everything called e.g. `Object` or `Any`. It seems you have the same in math. Everything is a **mathematical object**.

In many programming languages , types are also objects themselves. There seems to be an analogy in mathematics. **mathematical structures** look like types to me. As a programmer , I would say these have **mathematical objects** as instances. However , the **mathematical structure** is itself also an object, just like a type can be an object in programming.

And like programming there is a type hierarchy. If I understand correctly an **algebraic structure** is kind of like a subtype of refinement of the **mathematical structure** concept.

When I look at things like **fields** and **spaces** , this reminds of **parameterized types** in programming. E.g. `Vector2D{Integer}` or `Vector2D<Int>` depending on the language you use are 2D vectors parameterized on the Integer type, meaning their x and y coordinates are integers, rather than say floating point.

As far as I understand , you express vector spaces in a similar fashion. You say a vector space **over** some field. The field seem a bit analogous to a **type parameter** to me. The field would be the natural numbers, real numbers of whatever. The field defines the components making up the  individual vectors in the vector space as well as the numbers which you may multiply a vector with e.g.

Again I know these kinds of analogies are flawed, but if we were to attempt to create analogies, is there some truth to what I am guessing here or do I have a profound misunderstanding of these concepts?

Comment: Have you heard about '*Type theory*'?

Comment: @Berci I have dabbled in Type theory while dabbling in Haskell. Only superficial exposure. Mainly I need to grasp the math language so it is easier for me to read explanations for things like Tensors. Does type theory bridge math concepts and programming concepts in any way? Type theory won't tell me how to think of a vector space or field e.g. will it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the analogies. While I agree that there is not necessarily any perfect 1-1 mapping of the ideas of CS to those of algebra or linear algebra, analogies can certainly help in building intuition. For instance, I had a tough time "picturing" the hierarchy of rings, integral domains, principal ideal domains, unique factorization domains, euclidean domains, etc... The inclusion diagrams made sense, but I didn't feel like I understood it concretely. (Of course, one could always respond with the famous von Neumann quote, "...in mathematics, you don't understand things. You just get used to them.") The best I could do, having a background in CS, was imagine some class inheritance scheme where the level of an object in the hierarchy dictated how much the class was able to do, so to speak. The more defined the class was, the more tasks it was able to complete. A ring, for instance, has plenty of nice structure (we can add commutatively and multiply in a closed set), but not as much a Euclidean domain (where we can run Euclidean algorithms).

Your intuitions about parametrized types for vector spaces over a field $\mathbb{F}$ is a good example. Depending on the field that you assign (e.g. the reals, number fields, finite fields, $p$-adic fields), the vectors may behave differently under linear transformations.

Consider doing some online research on category theory. This field deals with the interaction of classes of algebraic objects via mappings. I've often seen interesting interactions between computer science and category theory and it might help build further intuitions. Good luck!

Comment: For the inclusions  between "Factorial rings", "PID's", "Euclidean rings" etc. one can give explicit examples and counterexamples, making it pretty "concrete" (you said "but I didn't feel like I understood it concretely" - this is the point - "concretely". We can do it concretely, like we can do it for "I don't understand concretely when a number is prime or composite").

Comment: Dealing with whether an integer is prime or composite seems fairly trivial in comparison to grasping the *category* of vector spaces or modules (for example). Absolutely, you can provide an example/counterexample for any of those objects, but that doesn't help you, in my humblest of student opinions :-), understand the category of those objects. Sure, I know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain and $\mathbb{Z}/(4)$ is not, but does that help me understand the category of integral domains? The OP was discussing parametrizing classes in CS to make this distinction easier.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant that dealing with whether an integer is prime or composite is not much more complicated than dealing with several types of rings  - if you do concrete examples and counterexamples. Actually, you often can do this with prime numbers and the ring of integers. Our discussion was not on categories, but only on what you said about Euclidean rings etc.

Comment: You're right - my apologies. I avoided discussing categories in the post for the benefit of the OP, but that's the basic idea. Creating a CS class of parameterized types is, I think, a nice analogy of a category. We define a [mathematical] class of these objects, $ob(C)$, with different inputs for each object (e.g. field, dimension) and define the possible ways to combine them with $hom(C)$. In a CS class this might be vector addition, for example. This is my first answer of this scale – apologies for my lack of clarity!

Comment: As for the relative difficulty of comparing primes and composite numbers with different ring types: I can only say that while I certainly feel comfortable with this now, I was *not* when first provided the 8 definitions in one lecture that you need to keep straight; though this may be more of a comment on the structure of the algebra courses I've taken... Thanks for the discussion!

Answer (score 1):

While this question is itself pretty open-ended, I'd like to make the suggestion of picking up and diving into the code of your favorite symbolic math manipulation library. Examples for the same would be [SymEngine](https://github.com/symengine/symengine) for C++, [SymPy](https://github.com/sympy/sympy) for Python, certain libraries that are a part of the Julia language and so on.

A number of these packages make use of OOPS paradigm in modelling relationships between different abstract concepts. For example, you'd have Integers inheriting from Rationals, which in turn would be inheriting from Reals. Then further on, you'd have specific classes for Polynomials, Rings and Fields.

Factoring those polynomials would make use of Galois Field Theory and other approaches. In between inherited classes, you'll observe the intelligent use of functional overloading to simplify certain expressions, or derive meaningful computations. As you rightly mentioned the use of types, a number of these libraries expose mathematical constructs as types through template metaprograming as well (for C++ based libraries atleast).

All of these ideas have been modeled considering different philosophies in different packages, pivoting to one would be a personal choice to be honest. Nonetheless, each philosophy attempts to model different aspects of the connections that these abstracts constructs share, using well known programming design principles. Hope this helps, happy learning.

Comment: I use Julia myself. I am familiar with e.g. the Number hierarchy, and how e.g. numbers support many of the same operations as vectors, which make mathematically I assume given that as far as I understand the field of real numbers if also a vector space onto itself. So I interpret a vector space as being the bundle of functions supported by vectors and their possible variations in data definition. My motivation for all of this is to understand difference between Tensors and Matrices better. They may contain same numbers but are different types in the programming sense as far as I understand.